# How is this effect achieved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

How do you make smooth horizontal scrolling with easing as well as change the scrollbar look (it is at the bottom) http://wmnvm.com/work/studio-songes

Comment: on which browser should it work? i tried with ff and chrome, in both this site is completely broken...

Comment: Then update your browser, it works for me